# How do I add another run level (level 7) in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart, runlevel

Ubuntu has 8 run levels (0-6 and S), I want to add the run level 7.

I have done the following:

1.- Created the folder **/etc/rc7.d/**, which contains some symbolic links to **/etc/init.d/**

2.- Created the file **/etc/event.d/rc7** This is its content:

```
# rc7 - runlevel 7 compatibility
#
# This task runs the old sysv-rc runlevel 7 ("multi-user") scripts.  It
# is usually started by the telinit compatibility wrapper.

start on runlevel 7

stop on runlevel [!7]

console output
script
    set $(runlevel --set 7 || true)
    if [ "$1" != "unknown" ]; then
        PREVLEVEL=$1
        RUNLEVEL=$2
        export PREVLEVEL RUNLEVEL
    fi

    exec /etc/init.d/rc 7
end script
```

I thought that would be enough, but **telinit 7** still throws this error: *telinit: illegal runlevel: 7*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot; the runlevels are hardcoded into the utilities. But why do you need to? Runlevel 4 is essentially unused. And while it's not the best idea, you could repurpose either runlevel 3 or runlevel 5 depending on if you always/never use X.

Note that some *nix systems have support for more than 6 runlevels, but Linux is not one of them.

Comment: According to Debian's init page, runlevels up to 9 are valid. I would assume the same is true for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to add them (never needed to), but I'm pretty sure `/etc/inittab` is where you'd add runlevels.

Although I'd have to agree with Zathrus that other runlevels are available but unused. On Debian, only 1 and 2 are used, really. I'm not sure how Ubuntu has it set up, though. However, if you have a specific purpose, it should be possible to do. I've just never had to.